# How to make this template which using typedefed type in template constructor copmiles?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct W 
{
    typedef T TT; 
    W(const typename W<int>::TT & m)
    {
        std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int f;
    W<int>k( f );
    return 0;
}
```

vc11 compiles, but g++ does not work.

My gcc version:

`Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=d:/usr/app/mingw-w32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7
.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../build/gcc/src/configure --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --pr
efix=/c/bb/vista64-mingw32/mingw-x86-x86/build/build/root --with-sysroot=/c/bb/v
ista64-mingw32/mingw-x86-x86/build/build/root --enable-languages=all,obj-c++ --e
nable-fully-dynamic-string --disable-multilib
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.7.0 20111219 (experimental) (GCC)`

gcc error message:
`dd.cc:7:27: error: 'TT' in 'struct W<int>' does not name a type`

Comment: Please add the exact error message.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @juanchopanza: it is a snnipet from a big project which someone need to mantain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that.

In order to know what type `typename W<int>::TT` is, the compiler must instantiate `W<int>`, but it can't do that while already instantiating `W<int>` because the type is not complete at the point where the constructor is declared.

You have a circular dependency between the complete type and its constructor.

Clang gives a helpful error:

```
t.cc:7:22: error: implicit instantiation of template 'W<int>' within its own definition
    W(const typename W<int>::TT & m)
                     ^
```

Comment: @PrashantSrivastava, because VC++ is buggy and doesn't instantiate templates as the standard says it should

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it got compiled in VC++

But following compiles with MinGW g++ 4.7.2

```
 #include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct W 
{
   typedef T TT; 
    W(const TT & m) // remove typename W<int> or use  W(const  W::TT & m)
    {
        std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int f;
    W<int> k( f );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jichao W(const  W::TT & m) can be used too, why you need W<int> ?

Comment: definitly it could works, the canonical representation should be `const typename W<T>:TT&`. But actually I am asking for whether it is possible to use W<int>.